# Reporting shell script test errors in Jenkins pipeline without killing job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

In a Jenkins Pipeline, what is the recommended way for reporting shell script errors that make the build unstable (ie, scripts that perform a test, but shouldn't stop remaining tests if failed further on)

Ideally, we wouldn't cancel the build if a 'test' script fails, but report the error at the end. This could be achieved by wrapping 'sh' steps with a catch block and marking the build as unstable. However if we use a single pipeline, all these error logs will be mixed up in a single console log (I realise you can also drill down from the pipeline view but it would require hunting).

Is there a recommended way to report these errors?   Ideas include:

- saving errors in an array and printing at end
- capturing output and writing a junit file
- some sort of plugin that has a step to record errors?  That would mark the build as unstable if any were reported?

e.g.

```
def errors = []

try {
    sh "check-doc-style.sh | tee check-doc-style.log"
} catch (e)
    errors << "Doc style check failed : ${e}"
}
step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: 'check-doc-style.log'])

try {
    sh "sanity-checks.sh | tee sanity-checks.log"
} catch (e)
    errors << "Sanity checks failed : ${e}"
}
step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: 'sanity-checks.log'])

if (errors.size() > 0) {
    currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
    for (int i = 0; i < errors.size(); i++) {
        echo errors[i]; 
    }
}
```

For context: We are migrating from a Jenkins setup where we had a dozen jobs per branch to a single Jenkine pipeline Jenkinsfile to represent the whole thing. A lot of jobs were script tests that either passed (exit code 0) or failed. Error messages were viewed by looking at the console logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Exit-Code Handling

### Shell

As it's being written Pipeline plugin does not support return of exit code or output from `sh` step. However there is an open  [ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-26133) which tracks this feature. Thus `try / catch / finally` would be the default way to handle such situation.

There are other approaches, but theses are rather cumbersome, ie. :

- ignoring non-zero exit code in bash, ex. `set +e`
- redirecting output to external file

### Maven

```
sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -B -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore verify"
step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'])
```

`maven.test.failure.ignore` will run all tests even if some of then failed. Then `JUnitResultArchiver` can set build status to 'UNSTABLE'.

## Status Reporting

- In my opinion if you're running tests the most meaningful way to keep track of the results is to analyze them with `JUnitResultArchiver`.
- However if on other hand you would like to collect *warnings* and then based on importance change result status, think about using one stage or even creating dedicated one, ie. `stage "report"`, where final information could be clearly visible.

Jenkins 2.0 includes [Stage View plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Stage+View+Plugin) which presents Pipeline workflow in a clear way.

Comment: I guess you mean `set +e`. Bewilderingly, the minus enables, and the plus disables the "errors are fatal" setting.

Comment: What do you recommend for reporting test failures?  Just print at the end of the pipeline? Or knock together a junit xml report?